# jQuery.on('change') not firing

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm working on a big application, that has a lot of JS modules. In one of them this code is being used:

```
var tinput = tmpl.find('[name="Filter[TravelTime][Selected]"]');
tinput.val(ui.value);
tinput.trigger('change');
```

It simply changes the valuo of hidden input and forces 'change' state on it.

In another part I have this simple function:

```
$('body').on('change', selectorSlider, function(){
console.log('fired');
});
```

what it should do is to show log when input's value changes - but it don't fire.
I have tried also this way:

```
$(selectorAvailableHolder).find(selectorSlider).on('change', function(){...}
```

Also no success. The only way to fire the event is to use pure .onchange:

```
$(selectorAvailableHolder).find(selectorSlider).get(0).onchange = function() {...}
```

And this works... except one problem - selectorSlider is not always available on document ready (it is generated from ajax request and cached, so it works when cached - as it is available right on the stert, but dont when not cached - as I have to wait for ajax response which takes few seconds).

Is there any way to debug this and find cause why change event don't propagate correctly?

There might be some typos in the code as I'm writting it dirrectly here (no access to oryginal code right now).

selectorSlider is defined this way:

```
var selectorSlider = '[name="Filter[TravelTime][Selected]"], [name="Filter[FlightTime][Selected]"]';
```

Comment: what is `selectorSlider` here? object, variable, if selector then what it is?

Comment: I have added info about selectorSlider to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tinput = tmpl.find('[name="Filter[TravelTime][Selected]"]');
tinput.val(ui.value);
$('body').trigger('change:filter', [ tinput ]);
```

on body

```
$('body').on('change:filter', function(event, tinput){
  console.log(tinput, 'fired change');
});
```

Comment: It will not work, as second part is placed in different module that does not anything about variables from first part.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski, do you tried this code? From 1st trigger - you send your `tinput`

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow - you suggest that second part tinput is just a name and it doesn't require it to be defined first?

Comment: @MarcinBobowski, tinput sended from `$('body').trigger('change:filter', [ tinput ]);` if you do not need this, you may remove it. On 2nd part you get it from `function(event, tinput){`, also will need remove

Comment: Ok, you are a genius :). Now please point me in a direction where I can find out why this works :).

Comment: Ok. "on" method is "live". You bind `body` to listen event `change:filter`, and if you set arguments of function which handled this event. And first part you fire trigger `body` `$('body').trigger('change:filter', [ tinput ]);` and sent tinput.

Comment: I know I can change 'body' with closest "existing" element that will hold the event. But I'm not quite sure why standard method used in question might not work (`trigger('change')`), and this one works.

Comment: when you `$('body').on('change', selectorSlider, ...` selectorSlider have to exists, but i think is not. If is not exists this event not handled. After you trigger eleemnt which do not have active listener. Bad english , sorry )

Comment: Dont worry, I get what you mean... But... I always thought that `$('body').on('change', selectorSlider, ...` works as old delegate - so whenever the selector will appear in dom, the `on` handler will attach - it should work as old .delegate

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(selectorAvailableHolder).on('change', selectorSlider, function(){...}
```

Good luck!!

Comment: That would be to easy. Using body makes it more generic and error proof, so using more specific selector won;t change anything.